# @Embeddable Issue with Spring and Hibernate3

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I am having an issue with mapping my entities to achieve a many-to-many join table using @Embeddable class as the join class representative. Basically here is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

I followed the tutorials given in the Java Hibernate Persistence book and I am still receiving errors from these methods:

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: nz.co.doltech.ims.project.server.entities.CategoryEntity.incidentCategoryJoins[nz.co.doltech.ims.project.server.entities.IncidentCategoryJoin]
>     at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1185)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:710)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:645)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:65)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1716)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1423)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1375)
>       at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:720)
>       at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:188)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)

I am setting up hibernate using spring:

> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean

**Spring Appcontext.xml:**

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
  <context:annotation-config />
  <context:component-scan base-package="nz.co.doltech.ims" />
  <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

  <!-- Configurer that replaces ${...} placeholders with values from a properties file -->
  <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
      <list>
         <value>classpath:nz/co/doltech/ims/paths.properties</value>
         <value>classpath:nz/co/doltech/ims/project/project.properties</value>
         <value>classpath:nz/co/doltech/ims/framework/framework.properties</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="no"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- Hibernate Data Source -->
  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${project.database.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${project.database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${project.database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${project.database.password}" />
  </bean>

  <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"><!-- depends-on="flyway" -->
    <!-- property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration" /-->
    <property name="dataSource">
      <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
      <list>
        <value>${paths.project}.server.entities</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${project.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${project.hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${project.hibernate.hbm2ddl}</prop>
        <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <!-- Transaction manager for a single Hibernate SessionFactory (alternative to JTA) -->
  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  </bean>

</beans>
```

Here are my annotated entity classes

**CategoryEntity.java:**

```java
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class CategoryEntity implements Entity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id = Entity.UNSAVED_ID;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 128)
    private String name;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 512)
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    private Set<IncidentCategoryJoin> incidentCategoryJoins;

    @JoinTable(
        name = "category_categorytype",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    )
    private Set<CategoryTypeJoin> categoryTypeJoins;

    // id column
    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // name column
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // description column
    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    // incident join columns
    public Set<IncidentCategoryJoin> getIncidentCategoryJoins() {
        return incidentCategoryJoins;
    }
    public void setIncidentCategoryJoins(Set<IncidentCategoryJoin> 
        incidentCategoryJoins) {
        this.incidentCategoryJoins = incidentCategoryJoins;
    }

    // category type join columns
    public Set<CategoryTypeJoin> getCategoryTypeJoins() {
        return categoryTypeJoins;
    }
    public void setCategoryTypeJoins(Set<CategoryTypeJoin> categoryTypeJoins) {
        this.categoryTypeJoins = categoryTypeJoins;
    }
}
```

**IncidentsEntity.java:**

```java
@javax.persistence.Entity(name = "incidents")
public class IncidentEntity implements Entity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id = Entity.UNSAVED_ID;

    @Basic
    private String owner;

    @Column(length = 256)
    private String description;

    @Column(name="creation_date")
    private String creationDate;

    @Column(length = 128)
    private String title;

    @Column(length = 20)
    private String date;

    @Column(name="location_details", length = 512)
    private String locationDetails;

    @Column(name="authorities_involved", length = 512)
    private String authInvolved;

    private int status;
    private int state;

    @Column(name="sub_state")
    private int subState;

    @Column(name="reported_by")
    private int reportedBy;

    @JoinTable(
        name = "incident_category",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "incident_id")
    )
    @Embedded
    private Set<IncidentCategoryJoin> incidentCategoryJoins;

    // id column
    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // description column
    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    // owner column
    public String getOwner() {
        return this.owner;
    }
    public void setOwner(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    // creation date column
    public String getCreationDate() {
        return this.creationDate;
    }
    public void setCreationDate(String creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    // title column
    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    // date column
    public String getDate() {
        return this.date;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    // location details column
    public String getLocationDetails() {
        return locationDetails;
    }
    public void setLocationDetails(String locationDetails) {
        this.locationDetails = locationDetails;
    }

    // authorities involved column
    public String getAuthInvolved() {
        return authInvolved;
    }
    public void setAuthInvolved(String authInvolved) {
        this.authInvolved = authInvolved;
    }

    // status column
    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    // state column
    public int getState() {
        return state;
    }
    public void setState(int state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    // sub state column
    public int getSubState() {
        return subState;
    }
    public void setSubState(int subState) {
        this.subState = subState;
    }

    // reported by column
    public int getReportedBy() {
        return reportedBy;
    }
    public void setReportedBy(int reportedBy) {
        this.reportedBy = reportedBy;
    }

    // categories join columns
    public Set<IncidentCategoryJoin> getIncidentCategoryJoins() {
        return incidentCategoryJoins;
    }
    public void getIncidentCategoryJoins(Set<IncidentCategoryJoin> 
        incidentCategoryJoins) {
        this.incidentCategoryJoins = incidentCategoryJoins;
    }
}
```

**CategoryTypeEntity.java:**

```java
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "categorytypes")
public class CategoryTypeEntity implements Entity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id = Entity.UNSAVED_ID;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 128)
    private String name;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 512)
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "categoryType")
    private Set<CategoryTypeJoin> categoryTypeJoins;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "categoryType")
    private Set<IncidentCategoryJoin> incidentCategoryJoins;

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Set<CategoryTypeJoin> getCategoryTypeJoins() {
        return categoryTypeJoins;
    }
    public void setCategoryTypeJoins(Set<CategoryTypeJoin>
        categoryTypeJoins) {
        this.categoryTypeJoins = categoryTypeJoins;
    }
}
```

So I am joining these tables with the @Embeddable annotation so that hibernate can map it into the entities. But as you can see in the error message, it is not mapping at all.

**IncidentCategoryJoin.java:**

```java
@Embeddable
public class IncidentCategoryJoin implements Serializable {

    @Parent // Optional back-pointer
    private IncidentEntity incident;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="category_id",
        insertable = false,
        updatable = false)
    private CategoryEntity category;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="categorytype_id",
        insertable = false,
        updatable = false)
    private CategoryTypeEntity categoryType;

    public IncidentCategoryJoin() {}

    public IncidentCategoryJoin(
            IncidentEntity incident,
            CategoryEntity category,
            CategoryTypeEntity categoryType) {
        // Set fields
        this.incident = incident;
        this.category = category;
        this.categoryType = categoryType;

        // Guarantee referential integrity
        incident.getIncidentCategoryJoins().add(this);
        category.getIncidentCategoryJoins().add(this);
    }

    public IncidentEntity getIncident() {
        return incident;
    }
    public void setIncident(IncidentEntity incident) {
        this.incident = incident;
    }

    public CategoryEntity getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
    public void setCategory(CategoryEntity category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public CategoryTypeEntity getCategoryType() {
        return categoryType;
    }
    public void setCategoryType(CategoryTypeEntity categoryType) {
        this.categoryType = categoryType;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o != null && o instanceof IncidentCategoryJoin) {
            IncidentCategoryJoin that = (IncidentCategoryJoin)o;
            return this.category.equals(that.getCategory()) &&
                this.incident.equals(that.getIncident()) &&
                this.categoryType.equals(that.getCategoryType());
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return category.getId() + incident.getId() + categoryType.getId();
    }
}
```

**CategoryTypeJoin.java:**

```java
@Embeddable
public class CategoryTypeJoin implements Serializable {

    @Parent // Optional back-pointer
    private CategoryEntity category;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="categorytype_id",
        insertable = false,
        updatable = false)
    private CategoryTypeEntity categoryType;

    public CategoryTypeJoin() {}

    public CategoryTypeJoin(
            CategoryEntity category,
            CategoryTypeEntity categoryType) {
        // Set fields
        this.category = category;
        this.categoryType = categoryType;

        // Guarantee referential integrity
        category.getCategoryTypeJoins().add(this);
        categoryType.getCategoryTypeJoins().add(this);
    }

    public CategoryEntity getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
    public void setCategory(CategoryEntity category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public CategoryTypeEntity getCategoryType() {
        return categoryType;
    }
    public void setCategoryType(CategoryTypeEntity categoryType) {
        this.categoryType = categoryType;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o != null && o instanceof IncidentCategoryJoin) {
            IncidentCategoryJoin that = (IncidentCategoryJoin)o;
            return this.category.equals(that.getCategory()) &&
                this.categoryType.equals(that.getCategoryType());
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return category.getId() + categoryType.getId();
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is not working for me?? Bare in mind that I have followed this method from the official Java Hibernate Persistence book, so in theory it should be working fine for me. I have been considering the possibility of a bug in Spring or hibernate. Anyway I would appreciate any help that I can get here.

Cheers,
Ben Dol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Err, no, this is not how many-to-many associations are mapped. The join table should not be mapped as an entity. You should have just three entities :

Incident <-> Category <-> CategoryType

The join tables should only be used to map the many-to-many associations, are described in the [official documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e11402).

Comment: The join classes here aren't entities, they are being mapped as embeddable classes to be used inside the entity mappings. This method is taken directly out of the [Java Persistence With Hibernate](http://www.manning.com/bauer2/) under the Advanced entity association mappings (An entity class that represents a link table with additional columns - which is something I will need here soon).

Comment: If the join tables have additional columns, then they should be mapped as entities (and not as embeddable classes), and you should have remove the ManyToMany associations and have OneToMany associations with the join entities instead.

Comment: I see, I will look into this. Aside from getting the join right, is there any reason this method isn't working for me anyway? (besides the fact that its not the correct practice here). It seems the @Embeddable annotation isn't being mapped at all here.

Comment: Associations can only exist between entities. Associations with an Embeddable are not defined and supported by the spec.

Comment: Cheers for the clarification JB, will progress this more now :)